# Yellow and blue graphical corruption on resume with Nvidia drivers 390

Tags: nvidia, graphics, suspend

Sometimes when I resume from suspend, I get yellow and blue graphical corruption in some applications (frequently in part of a webpage in Chrome, but sometimes in other places). The corruption is somewhat persistent – moving the cursor over it, moving the window containing the corruption, and scrolling the part of the window containing the corruption (e.g. in Chrome) all don't cause it to go away.

I'm using Nvidia proprietary drivers 390.77 on Ubuntu 18.04. My machine has an Nvidia GTX 1050 and Intel graphics:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

I've set up PRIME synchronisation with the instructions [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374405&p=13762069#post13762069) (tldr: put `options nvidia-drm modeset=1` in `/etc/modprobe.d/99-nvidia-modesetting.conf`), but I don't know if that's related. I'm not using Bumblebee or anything like that.

Is there something I can do to stop this corruption from happening?

Some examples:

[image] (here I could mouse over the video, and the corruption would persist)

[image] (here I alt-tabbed to Chrome and then to the currently-selected window, and the corruption persisted)